# Get all checkboxes inside a Group composite in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have dynamically added multiple checkboxes inside a group composite. Now, I want to get the status (checked/unchecked) of all the checkboxes inside the group composite. How do I do that?

I used the below piece of code for disposing everything. But in order to get the status, I need `getSelection()` method which is not available for a Control object.

```
for (Control control : grpTables.getChildren()) {
    control.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either

iterate over the children, test if a control is an instance of `Button` with style `SWT.CHECK` and then call `getSelection()` on the cast control

For example

```
if( control instanceof Button && ( control.getStyle() & SWT.CHECK ) != 0 ) {
  Button checkbox = ( Button )control;
  boolean selected = checkbox.getSelection();
  ...
}
```

or (preferred)

put all the checkboxes in a collection when they are created and iterate over this list when necessary